# Is Regex for Form Validation if I use the following?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, validation, code-injection

I know there is no harm in adding it either way but I'm curious...

If I was to use htmlentities(); with ENT_QUOTES and then mysql_real_escape_string(); the variable before entering it into the Database, then just use html_entity_decode(); along with stripslashes(); to display the information...

Would this still be safe and secure?

Comment: From people trying to maliciously attack a database from a form input...

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use htmlentities before storing data in the database.  In fact, it makes things easier later if you don't.  Only use htmlentities on strings as you echo them in HTML output (whether you fetched the string from a database or from some other source).

You don't need to apply stripslashes to data after you fetch it from the database.  The database has not stored the extra escaping characters -- unless you applied double-escaping by mistake.

Here's the right sequence:

1. Get data from a form

   ```
   $input = $_GET["input"];
   ```
2. Apply escaping *once*.

   ```
   $quoted_input = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($input) . "'";
   ```
3. Insert it into the database

   ```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable (column1) VALUES ($quoted_input)";
   $success = mysql_query($sql);
   ```
4. Later fetch it from the database

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT column1 FROM MyTable";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   $data = $row["column1"];
   ```
5. Apply htmlentities *once* as you output.

   ```
   echo htmlentities($data);
   ```

Comment: So taking the approach of just using mysql_real_escape_string, then entering to the database, that would be safe?

What about XSS too? I thought htmlentities would help protect against that?

Comment: not for xss attacks. I had a demo with a form and users added html code with a link to a xss javascript file that would run malicious code. I used htmlentities() so the html would be printed and not processed by the browser. of course if you allow html input regex might be better then htmlentities()

Comment: `htmlentities` has nothing to do with inserting data into the database. It's for display purposes, for data moving from the database through your app onto the screen.

Comment: So basically, htmlentities and mysql_real_escape_string would stop from injection and XSS JS files? But PHP regex is just extra security to really limit people to what you want them to enter? And JS Regex would just be merely for easier use/navigation on the client side of things? (So their not being directed from one page to another until they get it all right)

Comment: Yes, that's a good understanding.  I tend to use regexes to validate that the input is in the right format, not for security.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can answer the question on your own if you know what these functions are intended to be used for:

- **[`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities)** is to replace the HTML special characters `&`, `<`, `>`, and `"` and [characters that can be represented by entity character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html). This is used to encode data to be safely put out in any HTML context (especially with *ENT_QUOTES* so that it even can be used in single quoted attribute values). For example:

  ```
  <textarea><?php echo htmlentities('</textarea>'); ?></textarea>
  ```
- **[`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)** is to replace the [special characters in a MySQL string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html) while taking the connection character encoding into account (using [`mysql_client_encoding`](http://php.net/mysql_client_encoding) is required). This is used to encode data to be safely used in a MySQL string. For example:

  ```
  $query = 'SELECT "'.mysql_real_escape_string("\n\r\t\v\f\\\"").'"';
  ```
- **[`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode)** is the inverse function to `htmlentities` and replaces HTML character references (both numeric and entity character references).
- **[`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes)** removed the escape character `\`.

If you just want to protect you from SQL injections, use `mysql_real_escape_string` for data that is used in MySQL queries. You could also use prepared statements or parameterized query builder (see [SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), [PDO – Prepared Statements und Stored Procedures](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), [MySQLi::prepare](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare), et al.).

Answer (score 0):

are you asking if you still need regex as form validation next to all those functions?

if that is what you are asking then in my opinion yes, you can never be safe enough. I've just written a validation class with functions that clean up the code and other functions with regex when I need a specific input.